# Range of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question relates to the range ($\mathcal{R}$) of matrices and their intersection in a simple context.

First, let's take the simplified case where

$Ax = b$,

with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$, then if there exists a non-trivial solution, we know that

$\mathcal{R}(b) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A)$.

Now, what if $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 2}$ and, accordingly, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 2}$. Does it make sense to state the same as above, namely, that a non-trivial solution implies that

$\mathcal{R}(b) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A)$,

or is it more like stating $\mathcal{R}(b) \cap \mathcal{R}(A) \neq \emptyset$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y\in \mathcal R (b) \implies\exists z:bz=y\implies Axz=y\implies y\in \mathcal R(A)$

Thus it makes sense (and is correct) to say $\mathcal{R}(b) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A)$.